# Google BigQuery asking for JOIN EACH but I'm already using it

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query in BigQuery which has two sub selects and a join, but I can't get it to work. What I'm doing as a workaround is to run the subselects by themselves, then saving them as tables, then doing another query with a join, but I think I should be able to do this with one query.

I'm getting the error:

`Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH. For more details, please see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins`

but I'm already using a join each. I've tried using a cross join and using group by each but those give me different errors. The other questions on Stack Overflow about this topic don't help, one says it was a bug in BigQuery and the other was somebody using 'cross join each'...

Below is my sql, forgive me if it's full of errors but I think it should work:

```
select
t1.device_uuid,
t1.session_uuid,
t1.nth,
t1.Diamonds_Launch,
t2.Diamonds_Close
from (
    select
    device_uuid,
    session_uuid,
    nth,
    sum(cast([project_id].[table_id].attributes.Value as integer)) as Diamonds_Launch
    from [project_id].[table_id]
    where name = 'App Launch'
    and attributes.Name = 'Inventory - Diamonds'
    group by device_uuid, session_uuid, nth
    ) as t1
join each (
    select
    device_uuid,
    session_uuid,
    nth,
    sum(cast([project_id].[table_id].attributes.Value as integer)) as Diamonds_Close
    from [project_id].[table_id]
    where name = 'App Close'
    and attributes.Name = 'Inventory - Diamonds'
    group by device_uuid, session_uuid, nth
    ) as t2
on t1.device_uuid = t2.device_uuid
and t1.session_uuid = t2.session_uuid
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a `GROUP BY` inside a `JOIN EACH`. `GROUP BY` hits limits with cardinality (the number of distinct values) and the final grouping is not parallelizable. This limits BigQuery's ability to do the join.

If you change the `GROUP BY` to `GROUP EACH BY`, this will most likely work.

(yes, I realize that this is unpleasant and non-standard. The BigQuery team is currently working hard on making things like this 'just work'.)

Answer (score 3):

This can be combined to one single query:

```
SELECT device_uuid,
       session_uuid,
       nth,
       SUM(IF (name = 'App Launch', INTEGER([project_id].[table_id].attributes.Value), 0)) AS Diamonds_Launch,
       SUM(IF (name = 'App Close', INTEGER([project_id].[table_id].attributes.Value), 0)) AS Diamonds_Close,
FROM [project_id].[table_id]
WHERE attributes.Name = 'Inventory - Diamonds'
GROUP BY device_uuid,
         session_uuid,
         nth
```

You also have to use GROUP EACH for large tables.

Comment: Thanks Pentium10, I thought there should be a way to do that with one SELECT statement but I couldn't figure it out.